# Equivalent for rxjs every() in Rx.Net?

Tags: c#, rxjs, system.reactive

I'm using **Rx.Net**.
How do I filter out ***every N-th occurence*** in a stream of events. 
In Rx.js there exists an **every**() method. Can I use that for this purpose?  Every() does not exist in Rx.Net, what is the equivalent then?

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/all.html) the `every()` operator in Rx.js is a synonym for the `All` operator.

> Pass a predicate function to the All operator that accepts an item emitted by the source Observable and returns a boolean value based on an evaluation of that item. **RxJS implements this operator as every. The following example shows how to use this operator**

The `All()` operator is available in .Net, see [this](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/06_Inspection.html#All)

> **All**
>
> determine whether all items emitted by an Observable meet some criteria

Anyway, every time I encounter rx specific language translations I always take a look at this link: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html

Bear I'm mind though that I do not see any overload that gives every N-th occurrence of a stream. You sure it is the `every()` method you need?

Comment: every() rx.js ==  all() rx.net

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, RxJs's `every` == Rx.Net `All`, as Peter's answer described.

The functionality you described though (including/excluding every nth element) is available through an overload of the `Where` operator:

```
var sample = Observable.Range(1, 10);
var excludeEveryThirdElement = sample
    .Where((_, index) => index % 3 != 2);
```